# Dynamic grid control : Error - Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I need to create some `TextBox`es inside a `Grid` dynamically. I put a `ContentControl` inside the main grid and bound it to a property named `DynamicGrid`.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ContentControl
                    Grid.Row="0" 
                    Content="{Binding SomethingElse}" />
    <ContentControl
                    Grid.Row="1" 
                    Content="{Binding DynamicGrid}" />
            
</Grid>
```

`DynamicGrid` is a property of type `Grid`.
Based on some conditions and calculations, I create varying number of `TextBox`es (every minute) and set a list property `TextBoxList`. I need to place these `TextBox`es inside the `DynamicGrid`.

```
foreach (var textBox in TextBoxList)
{
   DynamicGrid.Children.Add (textBox);  // Here I get the exception
}
```

But then I get this exception inside the `foreach` loop:

> Specified Visual is already a child of another `Visual` or the root of a `CompositionTarget`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to clear the list of children before adding new ones, like `DynamicGrid.Children.Clear();`.

Comment: @thatguy ya sure. But the exception is there.

Comment: Are you sure your `TextBoxList` does not contain duplicates, e.g. the same `TextBox` instance multiple times? You could simply test this by using LINQ:
`var areTextBoxesUniqueInstances = TextBoxList.Distinct().Count() == TextBoxList.Count();`

Comment: @thatguy Oh. That was the issue ! some logic issue! items got duplicated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In WPF, each control can only have a single parent in the element tree. This was a design decision. If it was not implemented like this, e.g. `DataContext` inheritance or relative source bindings would be ambiguous among other mechanisms failing.

> Specified Visual is already a child of another `Visual` or the root of a `CompositionTarget`.

The error message tells you that a control was already added as child of another control, effectively setting its parent, but you try to assign another parent, which is illegal before detaching it from the current control.

This leaves two scenarios in your code that trigger the error.

1. You previously added a `TextBox` to `DynamicGrid` and try to add the same instance in the second run without removing the previous one. In this case you could remove all children from `DynamicGrid` with `DynamicGrid.Children.Clear();` prior to populating it again.
2. You cleared the `DynamicGrid`, but your `TextBoxList` contains duplicate items, so you reuse the same `TextBox` instance which gets added to `DynamicGrid` more than once. You can check this e.g. using LINQ.

   ```
   var areTextBoxesUniqueInstances = TextBoxList.Distinct().Count() == TextBoxList.Count();
   ```

   In this case ensure to create a unique `TextBox` instance for each item.